# concatenation result add two lists

Tags: python

Create two lists by taking inputs from the user. First input is number of elements and second input is values in the list. Each list should only contain string as its member elements. Create a resultant list such that this list contains the concatenation result of elements of first list with each element of second list

Create two lists by taking inputs from the user. First input is number of elements and second input is values in the list. Each list should only contain string as its member elements. Create a resultant list such that this list contains the concatenation result of elements of first list with each element of second list.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(map(''.join,zip(input('value: ')*int(input('number of elements: ')),input('value: ')*int(input('number of elements: '))))))
```

creates two lists
concatenates corresponding elements
returns one list